# How to add parameter to this thymeleaf link, if I need to have an id parameter also?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need id to be there and this parameter `sortField=${sortField}`. How can this be done?

```
 th:href="@{/admin/orders/decline/{id}(id=${order.id})}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add it as an extra parameter (without a placeholder).

```
th:href="@{/admin/orders/decline/{id}(id=${order.id},sortField=${sortField})}"
```

See the last example [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html#adding-parameters).